# Is there a game or analogy for searching for a number $R$ that is multiple of some number $A$ but not multiple of another $B$?

Tags: concept-motivation, games

$\DeclareMathOperator{\lcm}{lcm}$There are many applications for finding the GCD or LCM of two numbers.  I'm now interested in finding anything that could be used to illustrate the following mathematical relationship.

Let $r = \lcm(r_1, r_2)$.  Find a divisor $c$ of $r$ such that $r/c$ is a multiple of $r_1$ but not a multiple of $r_2$ (or a multiple of $r_2$ but not a multiple of $r_1$).  Notice there are cases in which no such $c$ can be found.  For example, when $r_1 = r_2 = \lcm(r_1, r_2)$.

Is there any interesting motivation that [can] be put on this?

Comment: This doesn't quite fit, but the question somehow reminds me of Conway's [Sylver Coinage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylver_coinage) game.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but it's equivalent to asking for a set $C$ such that $C \subseteq B-A$. Such an $A$, $B$, and $C$ would satisfy $C \subseteq A \cup B$ (equivalent to $c \mid r$), $A \subseteq (A \cup B) - C$ (equivalent to $r_1 \mid r/c$), but $B \not\subseteq (A \cup B)-C$ (equivalent to $r_2 \nmid r/c$).

Comment: @Aeryk, how is "$c$ divides $r$" equivalent to "$C \subseteq A \cup B$"?

Comment: @Aeryk, perhaps you mean "analogous to" instead of "equivalent to".  So I think your idea is to find three sets that satisfy all of these statements.  Interesting.  In my case, the idea would be to start out with two given sets (since I start out with $r_1$ and $r_2$), say $A$ and $B$.  Then the problem becomes to find $C$ that satisfy all other statements, if any.  Cool. I'll analyse that to see if anything interesting comes out!  Thanks so much for the ideas.

Comment: Not sure if "analogous" or "equivalent" is the better choice of word. Either way, you consider a natural number to be a multiset of its prime factors and you get the translation(?) I described.

Comment: Note that the "cases in which no such $c$ can be found" are exactly the cases in which $r_2|r_1$: in those cases, if $r_1 | r/c$, then $r_2 | r/c$ since division gives a partial order. Conversely, if $r_2$ does not divide $r_1$, then $c = r\mathrm{gcd}(r_1,r_2)/r_2$ works (and, indeed, all examples are multiples of that). I can't think of any particular use for this, though.

Comment: @user3482749, the cases in which no $c$ can be found are those in which $r_2 = r_1$, so, yes, $r_2$ will trivially divide $r_1$.  But in such cases, $r_1$ would not divide $r/c$ because if $r_2 = r_1$ then $r = r_2 = r_1$.  So your conditional on the sentence ending with "partial order" is vacuous.  Can you verify your reasoning?

Comment: @user724963 That is not the only case in which no $c$ can be found (though I notice now that I had a typo: I meant $r_1|r_2$, not the reverse).

Comment: In which other case no $c$ can be found?